# Surrogate variable analysis fails with "subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to apply surrogate variable analysis using [Bioconductor's sva package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/sva.html). The example in [the vignette](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/sva/inst/doc/sva.pdf) works fine, but when I try it with real data, I get a "subscript out of bounds" error in `irwsva.build`:

```
$ R

R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
…
> trainData <- read.table('http://www.broadinstitute.org/~ljosa/svaproblem/trainData.txt')
> trainpheno <- read.table('http://www.broadinstitute.org/~ljosa/svaproblem/trainpheno.txt')
> testData <- read.table('http://www.broadinstitute.org/~ljosa/svaproblem/testData.txt')
> trainData <- as.matrix(trainData)
> testData <- as.matrix(testData)
> library(sva)
> trainMod <- model.matrix(~as.factor(label), trainpheno)
> num.sv(trainData, trainMod)
[1] 8
> trainMod0 <- model.matrix(~1, trainpheno)
> trainSv <- sva(trainData, trainMod, trainMod0)
Number of significant surrogate variables is:  8 
Iteration (out of 5 ):1  2  3  4  5  Error in irwsva.build(dat = dat, mod = mod, mod0 = mod0, n.sv = n.sv,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

An attempt to narrow it down with `debug()` revealed that `fast.svd` is being called on a 453 x 100 matrix of all zeros. (The dimensions 453 x 100 are the same as my training set.) This results in a `V` that is 100 x 0; the "subscript out of bounds" error is because `irwsva.build` attempts to index into `V`. There must be something about my data that causes this behaviour—but what?

As a possible workaround, I tried calling `sva` with `method="two-step"`:

```
> trainSv <- sva(trainData, trainMod, trainMod0, method='two-step')
Number of significant surrogate variables is:  8
```

That worked, but I need to subsequently call `fsva`. That failed because calling `sva` with `method="two-step"` resulted in `trainSv$pprob.b` being NULL.

So how do my data differ from those in the vignette? The training and test data are matrices in both cases. In the vignette the training matrix is 22283 x 30; in my case, it is 453 x 100. In the vignette, the variable of interest (*cancer*) is binary; in my case, the dependent variable can take 12 different values.

The last difference seems to be important, for if I reduce the range to [0, 7], it works:

```
> trainMod <- model.matrix(~as.factor(label), trainpheno %% 8)
> trainSv <- sva(trainData, trainMod, trainMod0)
Number of significant surrogate variables is:  9 
Iteration (out of 5 ):1  2  3  4  5  >
```

Thinking that perhaps 100 samples (columns) is just insufficient for 12 classes, I tried a similar dataset with 293 columns. (The data are from the same experiment, but profile the 293 individual samples rather than the 100 treatments.) It did not help:

```
> trainData <- read.table('http://www.broadinstitute.org/~ljosa/svaproblem/trainData3.txt')
> trainpheno <- read.table('http://www.broadinstitute.org/~ljosa/svaproblem/trainpheno.txt')
> trainData <- as.matrix(trainData)
> trainMod <- model.matrix(~as.factor(label), trainpheno)
> trainMod0 <- model.matrix(~1, trainpheno)
> trainSv <- sva(trainData, trainMod, trainMod0)
Number of significant surrogate variables is:  11 
Iteration (out of 5 ):1  2  3  4  5  Error in irwsva.build(dat = dat, mod = mod, mod0 = mod0, n.sv = n.sv,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

If I limit sva to one iteration, it is able to run to completion, but I don't know if I can trust the results:

```
> trainSv <- sva(trainData, trainMod, trainMod0, B=1)
Number of significant surrogate variables is:  11 
Iteration (out of 1 ):1  >
```

Does anyone understand `irwsva` well enough to say why this is happening? Is there anything I can do to make it work on my data?

Comment: Well, the obvious question is: what differences are there between the vignette data and your dataset?  Matrix vs dataframe?, matrix dimensions not matching?, etc.  Your debug work isn't finished, by which I mean that a matrix full of zeros won't cause a "subscript out of bounds" error unless those zeros are being *used as* subscripts in some function call (or in some calculation of subscript values).  So, try to figure out what the contents of said matrix should be, and then why they aren't correct (assuming that really is the problem, which isn't certain yet).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I did some more debugging and added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The proximal reason for the failure is that `irwa.build` uses Fast Singular Value Decomposition, which only returns the *positive* singular values of the matrix, as noted in `?fast.svd`. In your data, the only values are zero, which is not positive, so you must use plain `svd` instead of `fast.svd`.

I have created a patched function `sva.patched` which patches the `irwa.build` and `sva` function slightly to handle this outside case. I essentially change one line in `irwa.build`:

```
# Before
sv = fast.svd(dats, tol = 0)$v[, 1:n.sv]
# After
if(any(dats!=0)) sv = fast.svd(dats, tol = 0)$v[, 1:n.sv]
else sv=svd(dats)$v[, 1:n.sv]
```

You can pick up the code [here](http://textsnip.com/aaa078):

But the real question is, why did these data end up producing a zero-value matrix? I don't know much about this method, but I can give you some clues.

From what I can tell, you used the functions correctly. However, if you examine the loop `irwsva.build` function, you will find that it will return a zero matrix if the `edge.ldfr` function ever returns 0. This function will only return zero when there are no p-values returned by `f.pvalue` that are above 0.8.

Breaking down `irwa.build`, this is how it starts with your data:

```
dat=trainData
mod=trainMod
mod0=trainMod0
Id <- diag(ncol(dat))
resid <- dat %*% (Id - mod %*% solve(t(mod) %*% mod) %*% t(mod))
uu <- eigen(t(resid) %*% resid)
# Iterations begin.
mod.b <- cbind(mod, uu$vectors[, 1:n.sv])
mod0.b <- cbind(mod0, uu$vectors[, 1:n.sv])
ptmp <- f.pvalue(dat, mod.b, mod0.b)
which(ptmp>0.8)
# Only one value
```

Now, the first time you go through the loop, there is only one p-value that is above 0.8. By the second iteration, there are none, which is the cause of all the zeroes.

If you run the same code on the vignette data, you will find that it has many p-values above 0.8, which is why it doesn't return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Response from John Leek (the author of `sva`) [on the Bioconductor mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2012-July/046639.html):

> This problem is likely because of the small number of genes/features
>   you are considering (453) and the high dimension of the response
>   variable (12). With so many different levels of the response variable,
>   many features are likely significantly associated with the response.
>   Part of the iteration in the sva algorithm is to downweight features
>   strongly associated with the response, so the whole data set is being
>   down-weighted to 0.
>
> I would suggest running only one iteration of sva. Usually it takes a
>   very small number of iterations to converge, and since your data are
>   relatively low dimensional in the number of features, this may be the
>   best that you can do if you are doing artifact discovery.

Comment: Follow-up: `num.sv` with `method="leek"` returns 0 for my dataset. When I repeatedly sample 453 genes from a 22283-gene dataset, `num.sv` returns 0 more than 50 percent of the time. This indicates that the reason I am unable to find any surrogate variables in my dataset is simple because all the 453 features are significantly associated with the variable of interest.